# showing white screen when navigate to next page in android using jquery mobile 4.5 and cord-ova 6.2 versions

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

> I am using this anchor tag for redirect the page. But i get white screen  when navigate to next page in android.`<a href="#" onclick="login()" class="btnSignIn" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Sign In</a>`

Comment: Please show your code . And mostly we use view rendering in cordova app E.g hide and show some content.

Comment: Hi thanks for replay. when i click the anchor tag i wrote the code for window.location = "../html/page.html" . that time first i got white scree then load the page. @Hassan Ali

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="login()" class="btnSignIn" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Sign In</a>

Comment: I used login function

Comment: window.location = "../html/home.html";

Comment: you have to bind events on document.ready function .Had you bind them in document.ready event.

Comment: please give one example code

Comment: i didn't bind the event in document.redy

Comment: You have to bind them document.ready function if you have any confusion in that . I can give you the code .

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your function in document.ready event in order to work correctly .Please define your all click events in deviceready function then it will work correctly .

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
       //call your click function here
            });
    }

};
```